Is it possible to map infinitely many primes to infinitely many other primes with a linear function?
I was wondering if this is even posible because I can not see an answer...
Given a subset $S\subset P$ from the set of prime numbers $P$. Let $S$ have an infinite number of elements. Is there any subset $S$ and a polynomial $Q(x) = ax + b$ on integer coefficients with $a \neq 0, b \neq 0$ such that it maps $Q\colon S \rightarrow S^*$ with $S^* \subset P$?
For example, if the twin primes conjecture is true then one can choose $Q(x) = x + 2$ and $S = \{x \colon x \in P,\, x + 2 \in P \}$ given that there are infinitely many twin primes.
I just wonder if there is a simpler provable answer.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Posting @SassatelliGiulio 's comment as an answer to this interesting
question.
Yitang Zhang proved the bounded prime gap theorem: there is an integer $k$ such that there are infinitely many prime pairs that differ by $k$. So the proved (not just provable) answer to the question is "yes" for the linear function $x+k$.
Whether there's a "simpler provable answer" is an open question. I think it unlikely.
